# How to import external library in Roblox script

Tags: import, lua, roblox

I would like to know in Roblox Studio :

- How to install an external Lua library, like this one :
  https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3
- How to import it in a script

If you have some documentation / tutorial, it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry if this is an unrelated question, I'm not terribly familiar with curl's capabilities, but is Roblox's [HttpService](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/HttpService) insufficient for what you're trying to do?

Comment: This library appears to rely on the `.c` and `.h` files in the `/src` folder. Libraries in RobloxStudio must be pure lua.

Comment: @kylaaa thanks for you answer, yes I heard also about this plugin and I can manage with  that. I just don't really understand the full pipeline to install external library and import them. By command line in Roblox, seems not working, using "luarocks install ...". I try to use the a Roblox plugin "Library Browser". It works if you know the name library. I found https://luarocks.org/ for list of Lua package, all can be used in Roblox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a disclaimer, this answer is how to generally use libraries in Roblox Studio. I was unable to get this to work with Lua-cURL for a few different reasons. Lua-cURL requires a C compiler and a system installation of the cURL library. These things are inaccessible in Roblox Studio, so as a warning, this answer will not work if you are trying to use a library that is not pure lua.

---

The best tool I have found for taking lua libraries and making it available in Roblox Studio is [Rojo, by LPGHatguy](https://github.com/rojo-rbx/rojo). Among its features is the ability to take a library of lua code and convert it to a `.rbxm` (Roblox Model) file, which can be dragged and dropped into an open place in Roblox Studio.

So here's the pipeline to get your code into Roblox Studio...

### 1. Install Rojo

Rojo is a tool written in rust, so the easiest way to get it is to also install [rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/). It comes with a package manager, cargo, and we'll use that to download the commandline version of rojo.

Then to download rojo, [follow the installation guide](https://rojo.space/docs/v7/getting-started/installation/) or simply use the command :

```rust
cargo install rojo
```

### 2. Get the source code

This step involves getting all of the .lua files for the library. In order for the library to work in Roblox, it must use code that will run in a Roblox environment, so anything that tries to access the filesystem will likely not work. Anyways, you can clone the git repository to get a local copy of it, or use Luarocks.

```
gh repo clone <REPOSITORY_NAME>
```

I personally don't recommend Luarocks, it is really annoying to get working on a Windows system, and the latest version expects at least lua version 5.4, and Roblox runs on a forked version of lua 5.1.

### 3. Convert the code to an .rbxm

Now that you have the raw lua files, we can package them up into a format that can be easily imported into Roblox Studio.

So open up a terminal and navigate into the source folder. Then use the `rojo build` command to package it all up

```
C:\> cd git\REPOSITORY_NAME\src
C:\git\REPOSITORY_NAME\src> rojo build --output REPOSITORY_NAME.rbxm
```

In the resulting `.rbxm` file, Rojo will convert all `.lua` files into ModuleScripts, `.server.lua` files into Scripts, and `.client.lua` files into LocalScripts. It will also convert directories into Folders.

Also, if a directory has an `init.lua` file, instead of creating a Folder, it will create a ModuleScript with the contents of that file as its source.

### 4. Use in Roblox Studio

Now that you have an `.rbxm`, you can simply drag and drop it into your place file in Roblox Studio. By default, it will land in the Workspace, but you can move it to ReplicatedStorage or ServerStorage or wherever you are organizing your code.

Then you can use the `require` keyword to access the contents of the library.

For example, if you were using Roblox's React-like framework, [Roact](https://github.com/Roblox/roact), you could use it in your LocalScripts like this :

```lua
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Roact = require(ReplicatedStorage.Roact)

-- Create our virtual tree describing a full-screen text label.
local tree = Roact.createElement("ScreenGui", {}, {
    Label = Roact.createElement("TextLabel", {
        Text = "Hello, world!",
        Size = UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0),
    }),
})

-- Turn our virtual tree into real instances and put them in PlayerGui
Roact.mount(tree, LocalPlayer.PlayerGui, "HelloWorld")
```

If your code didn't have an `init.lua` file, it is likely that all of the files are in a Folder, so you'll need to reach into the contents of the library to access the individual ModuleScripts.

Hope this helps.